# Wildcarding FULLTEXT search in NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with jquery autocomplete and I want to return suggestions even on partial word input.

Right now I have this query

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST ('$search_query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

It works well, but unlike the `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`, `BOOLEAN MODE` has a bad relevancy sorting.

So I'm trying to get wildcard to work in the natural language mode. As far as I know, it is not supported by default, but maybe it can be done some other way? Like using PHP function, for example.

Comment: Please add more information to the question, table schema, sample data, and expected results. Also which wildcard are you trying to use `_`, `%`, `*`, `+`, or something else?

Comment: Relevancy ranking in Boolean Mode isn't bad; and [the algorithm is well-documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html). However, results arent' sorted by default, unlike in Natural Language Mode. See @Adam's answer on how to sort results by relevance in Boolean Mode. ~ Short version, there is no PHP function or other work-around for this that wouldn't be hideously expensive in comparison to wildcard-searches in Boolean Mode. If you have particular issues getting relevant results in Boolean Mode, please update the OP to explain what the trouble is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost embarrassed to admit this, but I was faced with a similar problem with non-indexed full text searching.  I created a database table with my favorite word list, 18 of which look like this:

```
+------+-------------+
| ID   | WORD        |
+------+-------------+
| 2336 | Babble      |
| 2337 | Babbled     |
| 2338 | Babbling    |
| 2339 | Babian      |
| 2348 | Babied      |
| 2346 | Babies      |
| 2340 | Babion      |
| 2341 | Babiroussa  |
| 2342 | Babirussa   |
| 2343 | Baboo       |
| 2344 | Babu        |
| 2345 | Baby        |
| 2347 | Baby        |
| 2349 | Babying     |
| 2350 | Babylonic   |
| 2351 | Babylonical |
| 2352 | Babyroussa  |
| 2353 | Babyrussa   |
+------+-------------+
```

It's not very pretty, but you select the words which start with what the user types (WORD like 'bab%', as shown above for my list), excluding stop words, and then pass them into your natural language search.  Word lists are available in many languages, if your application isn't English.  You can add in lists of names, etc,  if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard won't work for Natural Language mode as it's an instruction used in Boolean mode.

You have to use `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses, as the MATCH function returns the relevance score that you would use for sorting results (`order by`) and keeping only non-zero results (`having`).

```
SELECT field,
    MATCH (field) AGAINST ('$search_query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
    FROM table
    HAVING score > 0
    ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: This is the default way of handling relevance sorting in Boolean Mode. Not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

You will need something resembling

```
SELECT *, MATCH(field) AGAINST '$search_query' AS `relevance`
WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST ('$search_query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Comment: Just before `WHERE`.

Comment: @RickJames but it's not working. `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean`

And normal requests in `BOOLEAN` and `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` do return everything correctly.

Comment: Ok, it did work after I put first `'$search_query'` in round brackets. But still, my goal was to get an adequate wildcarding in `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` and this method doesn't work until I write the whole word. What's the point of this? So weird...

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you.

```
SELECT  MATCH (field)
    AGAINST ('$search_query' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS result
    FROM table;
```

Comment: How would that accomplish what OP is asking for?